# Unnecessary portion in code - "wordlist loaded" at the end

Tags: python

Just have a quick question to check. I'm working on a word game and want to find the number of points of a given hand. I've gotten most of the code correct and it runs fine. However, I keep getting an extra part of the code repeated at the bottom and I would like to know how should I remove it? Here's the code:

```
def play_hand(hand, wordlist):

    """
    Allows the user to play the given hand, as follows:

    * The hand is displayed.

    * The user may input a word.

    * An invalid word is rejected, and a message is displayed asking
      the user to choose another word.

    * When a valid word is entered, it uses up letters from the hand.

    * After every valid word: the score for that word is displayed,
      the remaining letters in the hand are displayed, and the user
      is asked to input another word.

    * The sum of the word scores is displayed when the hand finishes.

    * The hand finishes when there are no more unused letters.
      The user can also finish playing the hand by inputing a single
      period (the string '.') instead of a word.

      hand: dictionary (string -> int)
      word_list: list of lowercase strings

    """
    print "Current Hand:", display_hand(hand)
    word = raw_input('Enter word, or a "." to indicate that you are finished:')
    handScore = 0

    while list(word) != ['.']:
        if is_valid_word(word, hand, wordlist) == True:
            score = get_word_score(word,n)
            handScore = handScore + score
            print word, "earned", score, "points. Total:", handScore, "points"
            hand = update_hand(hand, word)

            if calculate_handlen(hand) == 0:
                    print "Your hand has finished."
                    print "Your final score is", handScore
                    break
            else:
                print "Current hand:", display_hand(hand)
                word = raw_input('Enter word, or a "." to indicate that you are finished:')

        else:
            print "Invalid word, please try again."
            word = raw_input('Enter word, or a "." to indicate that you are finished:')


    if list(word) == ['.']:
        print "Total score: %d points" %(handScore)


n = 7
hand = deal_hand(n)
play_hand(hand, load_words())
```

Here's the code for load_words():

```
def load_words():
    """
    Returns a list of valid words. Words are strings of lowercase letters.

    Depending on the size of the word list, this function may
    take a while to finish.
    """
    print "Loading word list from file..."
    # inFile: file
    inFile = open(WORDLIST_FILENAME, 'r', 0)
    # wordlist: list of strings
    wordlist = []
    for line in inFile:
        wordlist.append(line.strip().lower())
    print "  ", len(wordlist), "words loaded."
    return wordlist
```

I get this in return:

```
Loading word list from file...
   83667 words loaded.
Current Hand: a i j m n w v
None
Enter word, or a "." to indicate that you are finished:jam
jam earned 36 points. Total: 36 points
Current hand: i n w v
None
Enter word, or a "." to indicate that you are finished:win
win earned 18 points. Total: 54 points
Current hand: v
None
Enter word, or a "." to indicate that you are finished:v
Invalid word, please try again.
Enter word, or a "." to indicate that you are finished:.
Total score: 54 points
Loading word list from file...
   83667 words loaded.
```

As you can see, there's an extra "loading word list from file... 83667 words loaded." at the bottom which isn't supposed to be there. Does anyone know what went wrong in my code?

Thanks so much!
Andrea

Comment: Can you post the full code including `deal_hand()`?

Comment: Is this an edX class assignment?

Comment: *"From the 6.00x course staff, please do not engage in this type of cheating. First off, this is a violation of the Honor Code. Secondly, the actions of the few of you engaging in this behavior puts a bad face on all edX staff and students. Please do not ask for homework help on Stack Overflow. Use our forums, and when our forums are closed, follow the Honor Code and do your own work."*

Comment: I didn't take this as a Coursera course, I actually went to the MIT OpenCourseWare site and downloaded the materials off it. This is the Spring 2011 6.00 course. I never knew that there was any Honor Code. So does this mean that I'm not supposed to get help on MIT OCW courses on SO?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps load_words() function is called again from some function else which is not seen in the question.

What if you remove play_hand() and show the output here?

Note: you can always use a debugger like pudb to check the program flow.